# PHP - Looking at the Web Link

Tags: php, echo

I am very curious on how to do this. I want a PHP script to look at the string after the URL link and echo the value.

For example, if I entered:

"http://mywebsite.com/script.php?=43892"

the script will echo the value 43892. I have seen this in most websites, and I think it will be a very useful to have in my application.

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 2):

You mean, something like

```
http://mywebsite.com/script.php?MyVariable=43892
```

? Variables provided at the end of the URL like that are available in the $_GET array. So if you visited the above URL and there was a line on the page that said

```
echo $_GET['MyVariable'];
```

then 43892 would be echoed.

Do be aware that you shouldn't trust user input like this - treat any user input as potentially malicious, and sanitise it.

Comment: Is it possible to have two variables in the link? Something link http://mywebsite.com/script.php?MyVariable=14?MyVariable2=21

Comment: @Kevin: yes, just use `$_GET['MyVariable']` and `$_GET['MyVariable2']` to access them. Also, you'd have to separate them with `&`: http://example.com/?MyVar1=14&MyVar2=21

Answer (score 0):

```
echo filter_var($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

The sanitation is because in your example the query string is `=43892`, not `43892`. The filter used ["remove[s] all characters except digits, plus and minus sign"](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php).

Comment: See my comment on @Frxstrem solution

Comment: @Colin The question did not include other data in the query string, so I don't think it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The way you usualy use query parameters is by assigning them like `http://mywebsite.com/script.php?var1=123&var2=234`

Then you will be able to access them by `$_GET['var1']` and `$_GET['var2']` in your PHP script

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean `http://mywebsite.com/script.php?43892` ?

You can either use apache URL rewriting or try to extract all entries from $_GET and look a the one which looks like a number or simply doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually parsing the URL like this

> $geturl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
>
> $spliturl = explode("?",$geturl);
>
> $get
> = explode("=",$spliturl[0]);
>
> echo $get[1];

:)

Answer (score 0):

Before I really answer your question, I just have to say that most sites - at least that I have seen - actually use `?43892`, with the `=`. This is also much easier than using it with `=` in my opinion.

So, now to the actual answer. You can simply extra the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) using [`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`](http://php.net/_SERVER).

An example:

*User requests* `index.php?12345`*:*

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
?>
```

Output:

> 12345

Note that you can also use something like

```
<?php
if(substr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 0, 1) == '=') {
  $query_string = substr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 1);
}else{
  $query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
echo $query_string;
```

to support `?=12345` as well as `12345`, with the same result. Note also that `?=12345` would not be available as `$_GET['']` either.

Comment: The problem with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is that if you use this url `http://mywebsite.com/script.php?43892&test=lol` then you'll have echoed "43892&test=lol"

Comment: When talking about what most sites do, I'm quite sure it will be ?var=43892, so you don't have to parse the variables your own, if there are multiple

Comment: @JochenJung: yes, you're actually right, but I was talking about the way he used it (with it as the only parameter)

Comment: @Colin: but you can't use `$_GET` either in that case, as you wouldn't no the name of the variable (i.e. `$_GET['43892']`) in advance, only its value (`''`)

Comment: Yep, you only know that and the fact that it's a number.

Answer (score 0):

I'de recommand [parse-url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) for this. The documentation contains all you (I think) need.